# Can not change BackColor of Label in Windows Forms once set

Tags: c#, winforms

First I created this array of LightGray block, and the button START. So the purpose is when I click START the chosen block will turn ForrestGreen:

Each of the LightGray block stored in an Label array called blockLabel. This blockLabel is added by the panel.

[image]

here's the code to handle the button:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
        CreateBlock();
}
private void CreateBlock() {
        blockLabel[5,0].BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
}
```

blockLabel code:

```
blockLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label[numCol,numRow];
        // Create many block label
        int i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < numCol; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < numRow; j++) {
                blockLabel[i,j] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label {
                    Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33*i,33*j),
                    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30,30),
                    BackColor = Color.LightGray,
                    TabIndex = numCol*i + j
                };
            }
        }
        // World is the panel
        for (i = 0; i < numCol; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < numRow; j++) {
                World.Controls.Add(blockLabel[i,j]);
            }
        }
```

The World panel I add by the Designer

When I click Start nothing seems to happen. Any help pls?

Comment: How have you made your blockLabels?

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce the problem...

Comment: Show your code creating the blockLabel array.

Comment: Is btnStart wired to the Click event handler?

Comment: blockLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label[numCol,numRow];
   
   int i,j;
   for (i = 0; i < numCol; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < numRow; j++) {
     blockLabel[i,j] = new 
      System.Windows.Forms.Label {
      Location = new 
      System.Drawing.Point(33*i,33*j),
      Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30,30),
      BackColor = Color.LightGray,
      TabIndex = numCol*i + j
     };
    }
   }
   
   for (i = 0; i < numCol; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < numRow; j++) {
     World.Controls.Add(blockLabel[i,j]);
    }
   }

Comment: World is the panel.

Comment: Please edit your question to put the extra information into it, rather than adding a comment.

Comment: @rene 's question still remains. When you're debugging, if you put a breakpoint in `btnStart_Click` and click the Start button, does your breakpoint get hit?

Comment: okay the breakpoint did not hit. So the problem is in the btnStart_Click then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your button control is not hooked up to the click event you have defined. You can do this through the designer by selecting the button, then in the `Properties` window, click the `Event` icon (lightning bolt), then scroll down to the `Click` event, and choose your method from the drop down list:

[image]

---

If you're adding the button programmatically, then you can simply add your event hander to the click event like so:

```
Button btnStart = new Button();
btnStart.Click += btnStart_Click;  // This adds your event hander code to the click event

Controls.Add(btnStart);
```

Comment: This is correct, however OP is creating these elements programmatically - could you add an example as to how he they could achieve this in code?